# Euler walk by joinning subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am studying the book: Graph Theory, Trudeau (Dover). Excersise 11, chapter 8, goes as follows:

Prove: if $n\ge2$ and G is connected with $2n$ odd vertices then $G$ has n open walks which, together, use every edge of $G$ exactly once.

The answer provided by the book is: Create a multigraph $M(G)$ by adding $n$ edges, each joining two odd vertices. $M(G)$ has a closed euler walk. Removing the $n$ edges from the euler walk of $M(G)$ breaks into $n$ open walks in $G$. each of which begins and ends at an odd vertex and which, togheter, use every edge of $G$ exactly once.

---

This at first glance it's ok. My problem is in the line *"...by adding $n$ edges, each joining two odd vertices."*(*)

Think in the following graph, $V(G)=\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H \}$, 
$E(G)=\{AD, BD, CD, ED, DF,FH,FG \}$. This graph fulfills the statement, but it has a flaw where my problem comes: you can only add an extra edge to $2$ pairs in this graph, because this is exactly the application of (*). Any extra edges **must** be between an even edge, and an odd edge, therefore invalidating the statement.

Is this right? Am I missing something?

Comment: I can add edges DH,EG, FC and AB.

Comment: In that case, the graph will be an supergraph of $G$, not a multigraph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph

Comment: A multigraph is PERMITTED to have multiple edges. Every simple graph is also a multigraph.

Comment: Then it is also right to say that a subgraph of a multigraph do the job (since any graph is a subgraph of itself). What you say and what I say is tricky, but nonetheless true.

Comment: The multigraph approach is necessary, because in some cases, e.g. when $G=K_4$, you cannot avoid adding multiple edges. In your example adding multiple edges is not necessary. I have no idea how to interpret your last comment.

Comment: If you have issues with multigraphs, instead of adding just edges, you can add edges with dummy vertices in the middle, so that the result of transformation will be just a simple graph.

Comment: I will think about it, the suggestion is pretty nice.